# Como aplicar condições neste template string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonisjs, indicative

Atualmente eu possuo esse objeto:

```
const messages = {
  required: field => `${field} é obrigatório e naõ foi preenchido!`,
}
```

Que printa o seguinte valor:

```
name é obrigatório e não foi preenchido!
```

Eu preciso aplicar uma condição nessa template string que altera o valor de field baseado em uma condição. Eu tentei algo como:

```
const messages = {
  required: field => `
   ${field => {
    if(field === 'name') {
     'nome'
    }
    if(field === 'address') {
      'endereço'
    } 
   }} é obrigatório e não foi preenchido
  `,
}
```

Porém quando eu printo eu recebo:

```
field => { if(field === 'name') { return 'nome' } } é obrigatório e não foi preenchido
```

E eu preciso:

```
nome é obrigatório e não foi preenchido.
```

Comment: Uma pergunta que sempre faço pra pessoas que são mais recentemente e já pegaram a época do CSS3+ e ES6, será que é realmente necessário? Tanto em CSS3 quanto em ES6 eu sei que tem uma série de coisas que parecem legais, mas será que realmente precisamos delas? Por exemplo, outro dia perguntaram como colocar um desenho em CSS como bg em baixo de cada TD, formularam uma resposta avançada e complexa, mas uma simples imagem em SVG com background-image resolveria e funcionaria melhor ainda ...

Comment: ... o mesmo digo sobre template strings, será que precisa mesmo colocar a lógica dentro da string? Não seria melhor setar uma var a cada IF e depois jogar no template já tratado? Será que precisamos de toda essa complexidade? Porque não o mais simples e intuitivo? ... Eu sinceramente acho que JS e CSS criaram coisas legais, mas nem tudo de fato é útil, na verdade parece que atrapalham mais.

Comment: Jovem, colocar expressões dentro de uma template string dificulta a leitura para caramba. Talvez fosse melhor repensar melhor na forma de criar essa string.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
const fields = {
   address: 'Endereço',
   name: 'Nome'
}

const messages = {
  required: field => `${Object.keys(fields).includes(field) ? fields[field] : ''} é obrigatório e não foi preenchido`
}

console.log(messages.required('name'))
console.log(messages.required('address'))
```

Eu adicionei uma condição ternária dentro da template string, ele reconhece sem problemas, não é possível utilizar `if` e `else` dentro do template string.

Em `Object.keys(fields).includes(field) ? fields[field]` estou verificando se há uma chave dentro do objeto `fields` que corresponda ao campo solicitado, se houver, ele traz a valor como resultado.

Como mencionado pelo @Guilherme Nascimento, é preferível colocar a lógica fora do template string para facilitar a leitura/manutenção do código

```js
const fields = {
   address: 'Endereço',
   name: 'Nome'
}

function getFieldText(field) {
  return Object.keys(fields).includes(field) ? fields[field] : ''
}

const messages = {
    required: field => `${getFieldText(field)} é obrigatório e não foi preenchido`
}

console.log(messages.required('name'))
console.log(messages.required('address'))
```

Comment: Funciona bem, porém eu posso ter mais de uma condição pra fazer, vou atualizar minha pergunta pra ficar mais claro

Comment: Excelente resolução, ficou bem organizado no final.

Answer (score 3):

Por questão de organização e leitura, é preferível evitar colocar expressões grandes dentro de uma template string.

O ideal seria formular a lógica fora da template string e guardar o valor numa variável, passando ela na interpolação da template string.

```js
const messages = {
    required: field => {

        let field_name = field;

        if (field === 'name') {
            field_name = 'nome';
        } else if(field === 'address') {
            field_name = 'endereço';
        }

        return  `${field_name} é obrigatório e não foi preenchido`
    },
}


console.log(messages.required('name'))
console.log(messages.required('address'))
console.log(messages.required('idade'))
```

Dessa forma, se você (ou outra pessoa) tiver que alterar o código, ficará mais fácil de implementar alguma condição ou lógica nova.